# PHP: Unserialize string

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

this is my database

[image]

**Input:**

```
a:3:{i:0;s:28:"Logo_final_SatuPintu (1).png";i:1;s:24:"Logo_final_SatuPintu.png";i:2;s:44:"WhatsApp Image 2017-03-24 at 7.04.01 PM.jpeg";}
```

Its serialize of dynamic input type file. And now i want to take that picture(s). Help me please.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHP documentation for unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/761632)

```
<?php
$result=unserialize('a:3:{i:0;s:28:"Logo_final_SatuPintu (1).png";i:1;s:24:"Logo_final_SatuPintu.png";i:2;s:44:"WhatsApp Image 2017-03-24 at 7.04.01 PM.jpeg";}');
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Logo_final_SatuPintu (1).png
    [1] => Logo_final_SatuPintu.png
    [2] => WhatsApp Image 2017-03-24 at 7.04.01 PM.jpeg
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Its work in my code.

Comment: @Gerald28 welcome ... :)